# Call a URL before a redirect, via PHP head()?

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers, apache2, http-redirect

I need to have 3 domains:

- a.com - where our script (below) will reside.
- b.com - has a tracking script we want to fire
- c.com - is our final destination, like a landing page

So, an advertising ad creative can be linked to http://a.com/track.php?id=1004&r=c.com, where 1004 is my affiliate ID. When this script is called, I need it to do something like:

```
<?php
setcookie('affid', $_GET['id'],time()+60*60*24*365, '/');
head('X-Something: http://b.com/track?id=' . $_GET['id']);
head('Location: http://' . $_GET['r']);
```

...where X-Something is just some header that Apache understands and attempts to connect on before doing the page redirection.

Trouble is -- I don't even know what HTTP header field would allow this. Is it possible?

Ultimately an affiliate could make his advertising creative link to something like:

http://a.com/track.php?id=1004&r=c.com

It would drop a cookie on a.com, fire a script on b.com, and then redirect to c.com. Is that possible? If so, what header do I need to use instead of the made-up-one I created called X-Something?

Comment: if the id is in the url, why do you need the cookie?

Comment: @Dagon It's because on c.com we make the customer download an executable program. Once the customer has installed and used the program, it connects back to a.com to a shopping cart for an upgrade. Without dropping that cookie on a.com, then I have no way of knowing which affiliate should get credit.

Comment: you could dynamically put the id in the downloaded file name.

Comment: @Dagon - That would mean that the EXE that gets downloaded would need to store the affiliate ID inside, like compile the EXE on the fly. That won't work in our case.

Comment: the file name, not inside, the program can then check what file name was used. just an idea, if it wont work for you then it wont. http is a stateless protocol there are limits here ;-)

Comment: Ah, but we don't give the affiliate credit until the customer has actually upgraded the product. (So, they download it, try it out, and then click Register to go to a cart on a.com to purchase it. It is only when they arrive at a.com's thankyou page that we need to give the affiliate credit for the sale.)

Comment: well if you want to do it the hard way ;-)

Comment: @Volomike You'll run into issues that way, if your user clicks the link to download the EXE, which drops the cookie, then the user does another action, (I don't know, clicks to download something else) from another affiliate, then the second affiliate will get the credit when the user upgrades... and, what about those of us who clear our cookies every time we quit our browser?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that such an HTTP header exists.

Instead, another solution would be to make PHP request the tracking script.  This could be done with `file_get_contents()`.  The method will return you whatever that is available at that URL, but in this case you don't need it so its return value can be ignored.

```
<?php
setcookie('affid', $_GET['id'],time()+60*60*24*365, '/');
file_get_contents('http://b.com/track?id=' . $_GET['id'] );
head('Location: http://' . $_GET['r']);
```

Comment: Really clever! Unfortunately in my case it won't work because I forgot to mention another requirement -- it needs to drop a cookie for b.com. Since file_get_contents() doesn't handle that because it runs at the server and not the client browser, this won't work.

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is only going to be solved with a META tag redirect and an IMG pixel. So, a.com has a script that drops the cookie and shows a blank page. That page loads the IMG pixel to b.com, then does a META redirect to c.com.

Comment: That could work in some cases.  But in the case where b.com is slow to respond, you may end up being meta redirected on to c.com before b.com has the chance to set the cookie.  Are you allowed to display the landing page inside of a frame?  If so, you could have a.com serve HTML with a hidden frame that hits b.com, while it shows the content from c.com in a visible frame.